# Why pycharm having error while loading .joblib file

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pycharm, decision-tree, joblib

I have a trained decision tree model file `music-recommender.joblib`. When I am using Jupyter notebook, I am able to load this trained model successfully and able to do prediction. But the same code I used in pycharm and it is showing error.

**In Jupyter Notebook**

[image]

As you can see, it is predicting correctly based on the trained model

**In PyCharm**

[image]

Does anyone knows why is it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the `joblib.load()` method but do not assign the output to any variable. And in the next step you are trying to use the `model` variable which is not defined anywhere above and hence the error.

You need to do:

```
model = joblib.load(...)
```

Comment: Hooray...it works. But may I know why the same code works in Jupyter Notebook? I am learning machine learning recently and all minor problems popping up now

Comment: @Anu It should not work in Jupyter for the given code. Are you sure you dont have `model` variable defined anywhere else in that notebook? Take a new notebook and then try the above code only!

Comment: I had a chunk of code before that defines `model` variable in my Jupyter Notebook. But I already commented it out and rerun that cell prior to run above code. So it means technically no `model` variable assigned right?

Comment: @Anu. By commenting the code, you just suppressed the execution of that code again. But it has been executed once and `model` is still present in memory. You can check that by just executing `model` in a new cell. To actually delete that variable, do the `del model` code.

Comment: Yes. you are right. I thought as long as comment it and run that cell, memory will be lost. After pasted that same code in a new workbook, it is having error. Thank you for the guidance.